# Stopping scheduled call to function after segue

Tags: ios, swift, function, segue

I've got a series of functions that call to one another and finally the last function calls back to the first to repeat continuously for an animation loop in one of my view controllers. I realize due to print statements that when I segue to other view controllers in the project, these functions continue to run. What is the best way to stop this from happening?

I can set a variable in viewDidDisappear and check for it at the start of a function to prevent that function's code from running, but there must be a better way to prevent a self.runThisFunction() from firing after a view has been segued away from?

Answer (score 0):

write **return** when you want to return when another view controller push.

> return;

Comment: That's what I'm doing, I'm setting a variable to true in viewDidDisappear, and then at the start of the function that repeats, I check the variable and use 'return' - just thought maybe there was a way to cancel a self.nextFunction() call IN viewDidDisappear so there wouldn't need to be any checking before it ran again

Comment: if that doesnt work, then set bool variable in UserDefault then set them true/False. as per need . and so as per boolean responce, you have to manage it